# vs 2017 unity tool for unity3d 2017.1

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, unityvs

Adding VS 2017 Unity tools in Unity 2017.1 for Mac edition. Adding tool is success but not show in menu bar.

How to use new unity version in VS 2017 unity tools?

Comment: Probably Microsoft not supported UnityVs for VS Mac Edition,
i think return fully windows version.